# SWAGGER: Dereferencing $ref from body parameter

Tags: swagger

Taking the petstore example,

I am trying to dereference the $Ref in the /pet -> put operation which is currently:
schema
$ref: #definitions/Pet

I am trying to resolve this but unable to get this text out from the json file.
This is what I have:

BodyParameter bp = (BodyParameter) param;
System.out.println(((RefModel) bp.getSchema()).get$ref());

I thought this would give me the above text out which I could later map with  a definition Map and resolve it but got the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: io.swagger.models.ModelImpl cannot be cast to io.swagger.models.RefModel

Would anyone know of a way to extract this string out from a body parameter and in general since the schema returns a Type Model?
I do not find a proper documentation source for the swagger parser , swagger inflector projects so hunting around through the source code itself.

Answer (score 4):

you would do the following:

```
Model model = bp.getSchema();
if(model instanceof RefModel) {
  RefModel ref = (RefModel) model;
  String simpleRef = ref.getSimpleRef();
  Model concreteModel = swagger.getDefinitions().get(simpleRef);
}
```

You should confirm that `concreteModel` is a `ModelImpl` but in the petstore case, it will be.

Comment: I had to use `RefProperty`s for some reason, but once I figured that out, this was very helpful!